# How can I place animated picture inside a stationary rectangle?

Tags: html

I want to place a image inside a rectangle and have the image move to the right while the rectangle is being stationary and not moving. My problem is that I cant manage to put the image inside the rectangle without the rectangle moving. I got the result I want with a specific screen size
by using margin and positioning the image but when I resize the window it will not be in the same place.

How to keep it in the image inside the rectangle at the same place?

```css
body { 
    margin: 0px;
}

.top-shelf {
    height: 5vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: rgb(40, 121, 197);
    opacity: 50%;
}

.logo-outline {
    border-radius: 35px;
    border: 5px solid rgba(4, 22, 29, 0.137);
    width: 130px;
    height: 130;
    margin-top: 1%;
    margin-left: 3%;
    padding: 30px;
}


.rotate-logo{
    position: absolute;
    top: 7%;
    left: 3%;
    transition: all 4s;
    -webkit-transition: all 4s; 
    transform: translate(130px, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate(130px,0);
    background-image: url('owl-logo.png');
    
}


.text-heading{
    text-align: center
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Cool Name</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="top-shelf"></div>
    <div class="logo-outline">
            <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/f1/90/8e/f1908e1ee89bc192c02e5dcb95296f5f.png" class="rotate-logo" width="70" height="70">
    </div>
    <div class="text-heading">
        <h1 style="font-family: courier;">Cool title</h1>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**strong text**

Comment: Hi. Could you generate a sample of an instance of your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try is just letting the image stay in the div, letting it flow on the page as it normally would. If the image is just in the div, it should automatically be sized to fit its contents. You could then affect the position of the image using CSS properties like margin or transform.

```css
#logo-outline {
  border-radius: 35px;
  border: 5px solid rgba(4, 22, 29, 0.137);
  width: 130px;
  padding: 2px;
}

#rotate-logo {
  height: 70px;
  transition: transform ease 100ms;
}

#logo-outline:hover #rotate-logo {
  transform: translateX(60px);  /* 130px - 70px width */
}
```

```html
<div id="logo-outline">
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/f1/90/8e/f1908e1ee89bc192c02e5dcb95296f5f.png" id="rotate-logo">
</div>
```